# Using MeasurementFormatter with Derived unit

Tags: swift, swift3, units-of-measurement

When I run the following code in a Playground the formatted string comes back as nil. What am I missing in the derived custom Measurement class?

```
open class UnitFlowRate : Dimension {
    open override static func baseUnit() -> UnitFlowRate {  return self.metricTonsPerHour }

    static let shortTonsPerHour = UnitFlowRate(symbol: NSLocalizedString("stph", comment: "short tons per hour"), converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1))
    static let metricTonsPerHour = UnitFlowRate(symbol: NSLocalizedString("mtph", comment: "metric tons per hour"), converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 2))
}

var measureCustom = Measurement<UnitFlowRate>(value: 12.31, unit: .shortTonsPerHour)
var measureSystem = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 12.31, unit: .inches)

var formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
var measureStringCustom = formatter.string(for: measureCustom)
var measureStringSystem = formatter.string(for: measureSystem)
print( measureCustom ) // This works
print( measureSystem ) // This works
print( measureStringCustom ) // This is nil - Why?
print( measureStringSystem ) // This works
```

Output:

```
12.31 stph
12.31 in
nil
Optional("0 mi")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update a few things in your code.

Firstly, you are using the `string` method on `Formatter` which takes `Any?` and returns an optional `String`. If you change the parameter name to `from`, you will use the method defined on `MeasurementFormatter` which returns a non-optional:

```
var measureStringCustom = formatter.string(from: measureCustom)
```

Secondly, you are using a `MeasurementFormatter` which has the `unitOptions` property set to `.naturalScale` (the default). If you change this to, `.providedUnit`, you'll see that you now get some output. The problem is that `.naturalScale` will use the appropriate unit for the given locale and there is currently no way to set what that is for custom `Dimension` subclasses.

So, the way to achieve what you what is to use the `converted` method along with a `.providedUnit` formatter, like so:

```
let converted = measureCustom.converted(to: .metricTonsPerHour)
var formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
print(formatter.string(from: converted))
```

Finally, you are probably still not getting the output you expect. This is because the `coefficient` for the `UnitConverterLinear` which is returned by `baseUnit` should be `1`. I expect you intended to define your dimension as follows (notice the scaled-down coefficients):

```
open class UnitFlowRate : Dimension {
  open override static func baseUnit() -> UnitFlowRate {  return self.metricTonsPerHour }
  static let shortTonsPerHour = UnitFlowRate(symbol: NSLocalizedString("stph", comment: "short tons per hour"), converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 0.5))
  static let metricTonsPerHour = UnitFlowRate(symbol: NSLocalizedString("mtph", comment: "metric tons per hour"), converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1))
}
```